# PostgreSQL comma separated column join in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, laravel-8

How to write join query for PostgreSQL comma separated column join in PHP Laravel. `FIND_IN_SET()` will not work as I am using PostgreSQL:

[image]

I need to join `Industry` table with `Company` table. While company can have multiple industries they are entered in `industry_id` column and values are separated by comma.

`FIND_IN_SET()` will not work as I am using PostgreSQL

Mysql query:

```
$companyData = "SELECT comp.* 
                FROM companies AS comp 
                LEFT JOIN `industries` as `indus` ON find_in_set(indus.id, comp.indusrty_id) > 0           
                WHERE comp.id = ".$companyId;
```

Comment: What is the actual output you want here?

Comment: Looks like an error in your datamodel, multiple values in a single column (industry_id that is). Optimise your datamodel and your problem is also gone.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I need to join  industry table with Company table. While company can have multiple industries they are entered in "industry_id" coloumn and values are separated by comma. 

FIND_IN_SET() will not works as I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: Great, what is the actual output you want here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Question updated with Sql query

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following trick on Postgres to workaround there being no `FIND_IN_SET` available:

```sql
SELECT comp.*
FROM companies AS comp
INNER JOIN industries AS indus
    ON ',' || comp.indusrty_id || ',' LIKE '%,' || indus.id || ',%'        
WHERE comp.id = ?;
```

Note that a much better solution here would be to fix your data model and stop storing CSV like this.  Create a junction table in which each record stores one industry ID and one company ID.

Comment: thanks for your help. But this FIND_IN_SET  will not works for Postgres

Comment: @SatheeshKumar Sorry, the reference to `FIND_IN_SET` was left there by accident, as I began my answer using your query as a starting point.  The typo has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could also create your own PostgreSQL function find_in_set():

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FIND_IN_SET(text, text)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
IMMUTABLE
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    SELECT $1 =ANY(STRING_TO_ARRAY($2,','));
$$;
```

It doesn't fix the real problem nor the performance issues you're going to face, but it works.